# Draw Image to Picture Box using AutoScroll but keep a Header Visible

Tags: vb.net, picturebox, autoscroll

I have a Picturebox which I draw a view to (Gantt View in this case) and it works OK - i.e., the view is drawn and the AutoScroll property allows the image in the PictureBox to be smoothly scrolled.

My problem is, the header of the image (e.g., the date headers in this case) scroll off the top of the display when I scroll down the image.

What I can't work out is how to fix a header to the top.  I thought about simply drawing a header into another Picturebox, but then I am not sure how to sync the header with the left-right scrolling of the main PictureBox

Can someone suggest the best approach to handling this, or do I need to revert to doing a direct draw and handle the scrolling myself?

I am using VB with VS 2015.

Many thanks

Phil

Updated - I am now using an off-screen Bitmap, but can someone look at the code below and let me know if there is a faster/better way to do this? It all works, but still learning and so always looking to do things the best way

```
   Public Sub MoveViewPoint(G As Graphics)
    ' G passed in from controls Paint

    G.Clear(Color.WhiteSmoke)
    ' _Plan is off-screen bitmap of image
    ' _HeaderHeight is height of the Header area in _Plan
    Dim Header_src_rect As New Rectangle(_HScroll.Value, 0, _Plan.Width, _HeaderHeight)
    Dim Header_dst_rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, _Plan.Width, _HeaderHeight)
    G.DrawImage(_Plan, Header_dst_rect, Header_src_rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

    Dim src_rect As New Rectangle(_HScroll.Value, _HeaderHeight + 1 + _VScroll.Value, _Plan.Width, _Plan.Height)
    Dim dst_rect As New Rectangle(0, _HeaderHeight + 1, _Plan.Width, _Plan.Height)
    G.DrawImage(_Plan, dst_rect, src_rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

    _HScroll.LargeChange = G.ClipBounds.Width * 0.9
    _VScroll.LargeChange = G.ClipBounds.Height * 0.9

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do all your drawing to an off-screen bitmap using the GDI graphics system.  You can draw your headers and the rest of the chart as 2 distinct stages in the same bitmap.  You would have to handle the scrolling yourself by watching the MouseMove event and checking the buttons status.

Comment: OK makes sense. So I have done this, but can someone look at the code added to the original Question and let me know if there is a faster/better way to do this? It all works, but still learning and so always looking to do things the best way

Comment: I don't see any major problems with what you are doing there, but updating control properties during paint is a little out of the ordinary.  It shouldn't really cause you any problems though, as far as I know.